# why say "$\mathbb{R}$-tree"?

Tags: functional-analysis

> **Definition.** An *$\mathbb{R}$-tree* is a metric space $(X,d)$ such that
>
> 1. there is a unique geodesic segment (denoted $[x,y]$) joining each pair of points $x,y \in X$;
> 2. if $[x,y] \cap [y,z] = \{y\}$, then $[x,y] \cup [y,z] = [x,z]$.

why this space name is *$\mathbb{R}$-tree* ?

Answer (score 2):

Probably to differentiate it from a graph-theoretic [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)) (which is also a metric space, but a discrete one). An $\Bbb{R}$-tree is what you get by "filling in the gaps" between the vertices of a tree.

Comment: so What is $\mathbb{N}$-tree?

Comment: @Sara I never saw that term. Or $\mathbb Q$-tree, $\mathbb C$-tree, etc.

Comment: There are trees on other groups as well.